# Google Apps Script setTimestamp to mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv, google-apps-script, jdbc

I am trying to create a google apps script that take a CSV file and pushes it into a mysql database. I have trouble inserting the date and datetime fields. The CSV date and datetime fields are formatted like this: 2015-12-04  and 2015-12-04 20:02:14 if there is time included. I am trying to use the following statement in my script. The 'date' field only has a date no time and seems like it may be working so maybe the issue is the time format?:

```
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO product_detail('
      +'Invoice,Sales_ID,Product,Report_Category,Menu_Price,Sales,'
      +'Net_Sales,Gross_Sales,Sales_before_Discount_after_Taxes,Sales_after_Discount_after_Taxes,'
      +'Gratuity,GST,GST_Inc,PST,PST_Inc,Total_Sales_Taxes,Total_Item_Discounts,'
      +'Item_Discount_Name,Item_Discount_Employee,Total_Invoice_Discounts,Invoice_Discount_Name,'
      +'Invoice_Discount_Employee,Table,Date,Date_Opened,Date_Closed,Day,Day_of_week,Week,Month,'
      +'Year,Open_Station_ID,Open_Station,Closing_Station,Closing_Station_ID,Open_Employee,'
      +'Closing_Employee) VALUES ( (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,'
      + '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1 ,data[i][0]);
    stmt.setString(2 ,data[i][1]);
    stmt.setString(3 ,data[i][2]);
    stmt.setString(4 ,data[i][3]);
    stmt.setString(5 ,data[i][4]);
    stmt.setString(6 ,data[i][5]);
    stmt.setString(7 ,data[i][6]);
    stmt.setString(8 ,data[i][7]);
    stmt.setString(9 ,data[i][8]);
    stmt.setString(10 ,data[i][9]);
    stmt.setString(11 ,data[i][10]);
    stmt.setString(12 ,data[i][11]);
    stmt.setString(13 ,data[i][12]);
    stmt.setString(14 ,data[i][13]);
    stmt.setString(15 ,data[i][14]);
    stmt.setString(16 ,data[i][15]);
    stmt.setString(17 ,data[i][16]);
    stmt.setString(18 ,data[i][17]);
    stmt.setString(19 ,data[i][18]);
    stmt.setString(20 ,data[i][19]);
    stmt.setString(21 ,data[i][20]);
    stmt.setString(22 ,data[i][21]);
    stmt.setString(23 ,data[i][22]);
    var date_insert = new Date(data[i][23]);
    var jdbc_timestamp = Jdbc.newTimestamp(date_insert.getTime());
    stmt.setTimestamp(24 ,jdbc_timestamp);
    date_insert = new Date(data[i][24]);
    jdbc_timestamp = Jdbc.newTimestamp(date_insert.getTime());
    stmt.setTimestamp(25 ,jdbc_timestamp);
    date_insert = new Date(data[i][25]);
    jdbc_timestamp = Jdbc.newTimestamp(date_insert.getTime());
    stmt.setTimestamp(26 ,jdbc_timestamp);
    stmt.setString(27 ,data[i][26]);
    stmt.setString(28 ,data[i][27]);
    date_insert = new Date(data[i][28]);
    jdbc_timestamp = Jdbc.newTimestamp(date_insert.getTime());
    stmt.setTimestamp(29 ,jdbc_timestamp);
    stmt.setString(30 ,data[i][29]);
    stmt.setString(31 ,data[i][30]);
    stmt.setString(32 ,data[i][31]);
    stmt.setString(33 ,data[i][32]);
    stmt.setString(34 ,data[i][33]);
    stmt.setString(35 ,data[i][34]);
    stmt.setString(36 ,data[i][35]);
    stmt.setString(37 ,data[i][36]);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) gives you the time since Unix Epoch in ms

If what you need instead is a timestamp string formatted in a certain way, you need to use [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format).

Sample:

```
  var timeZone = date_insert.getTimezoneOffset()
  var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date_insert, timeZone, format);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to just insert them as strings after changing the format of the CSV output. But this works too.